# $.ajax with auth silently failing in Safari (jQuery 2.1.3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

Anytime I try to send a `$.ajax` request (same origin) with `username` & `password` options in Safari, it just fails silently and never fires any complete, success, or error callbacks. The exact same request works fine in Chrome.

```
req = $.ajax
  url: ...
  type: 'POST'
  username: ...
  password: ...
  data: ...
req.done ...
req.fail ...
```

If I run the same code, but without `username` or `password`;

```
req = $.ajax
  url: ...
  type: 'POST'
  data: ...
```

The request actually goes through in Safari, but then obviously fails my server's auth. I'm not even really sure how to debug this. I tried dropping some log lines in jQuery's source around the `$.ajax` callback and it seems like the (attempted) authenticated request is never even going out in Safari.

**UPDATED 1/8:**

Also tested in Safari/Chrome with jQuery 1.11.0 and found the same results.

**UPDATED 1/8:**

gulty's beforeSend solution was the only way I could get basic auth to work in Safari:

```
req = $.ajax
  url: ...
  type: 'POST'
  beforeSend: (xhr) -> xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic username:password')
  data: ...
```

Comment: 'username' and 'password' are not valid jQuery.ajax options. They should form part of the 'data'. Whatever Chrome is doing, it's probably not what you think.

Comment: You sure? [The docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) say they go in `jQuery.ajax([settings])`. Anyway, the exact same thing happens when I move it into `data`.

Comment: I beg pardon, they are valid in the context of an HTTP access authentication request. My bad.

Comment: I can only think that Safari doesn't play ball HTTP access authentication requests. Does the error handler give any clues?

Comment: No, that's the thing, it's like the request never happens, so there's no done, fail, or always callbacks, and it returns an xhr-like object, but there's no response in it.

Comment: So does your network traffic indicate that a request was sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine for most browsers, anyway Safari isn't progressing the requests for reasons only the developers know.

There is a workaround - you need to set the request headers using headers: {} or within a beforeSend like so:

```
beforeSend: function (req) {
    req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "username:password");
}
```

This is an addition to your code - you should still keep username: / password: for other browsers since I haven't properly tested the code without those credentials.

Comment: I've seen some people base64 encode the `"username:password"` string; Is that necessary?

Comment: depends on what your server expects - you shouldnt have those credentials inside your js code visible for anybody tho therefor your need some security mechanism. I wouldnt use username/password anyway if it's on the same origin..

Comment: encoding it is more secure - else it's been send plain and can be hijacked. but you have to decode it serverside.. you can also get the credentials off a base64 encoded string tho..

Comment: This is working! Two things to note; 1) I did end up doing a base64 encoding of the auth string, and 2) The basic auth requires the string to look like "Basic username:password", not just "username:password". Thanks so much for pointing this out, gulty!

Comment: base64 is not at all more "secure" it's an encoding not an encryption